# Eloquent save() method not working inside for loop

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, slim

I have a table like given below and this table is going to be used for project images.

**id:** primary key

**project_id:** a column that has correlation with projects.

**order_num:** represents image list order for specific project (eg. interior view of project, exterior view of construction project, a different aspect etc...)

```
+---------+-------------+-----------+
| id      | project_id  | order_num |  
+---------+-------------+-----------+
| 1       | 15          | 0         |
+---------+-------------+-----------+
| 2       | 15          | 0         |
+---------+-------------+-----------+
| 3       | 16          | 0         |
+---------+-------------+-----------+
| 4       | 16          | 0         |
+---------+-------------+-----------+
| 5       | 16          | 0         |
+---------+-------------+-----------+
                 .
                 .
                 .   

         GOES ON LIKE THIS


What i want to do:

+---------+-------------+-----------+
| id      | project_id  | order_num |  
+---------+-------------+-----------+
| 1       | 15          | 1         |
+---------+-------------+-----------+
| 2       | 15          | 2         |
+---------+-------------+-----------+
| 3       | 16          | 1         |
+---------+-------------+-----------+
| 4       | 16          | 2         |
+---------+-------------+-----------+
| 5       | 16          | 3         |
+---------+-------------+-----------+
```

I use ***Slim with Eloquent***

I figured out something like this but i got **bad method** error for save() method.

```
$find = Images::where('project_id', '=', $project->id)->count();

$img = Images::where('project_id', '=', $project->id);

for ($i = 1; $i <= $find; $i++) {
     $img->order_num = $i;
     $img->save();
}
```

Am i doing something wrong? Any help would be very appreciated.

**UPDATE [!!] Both answers are give the correct results but according to the odan's information, apokryfos's answer is clean code. Thanks for your all helps.**

Comment: is it `order_num` or `order_id` you need to change?

Comment: ahh sorry for writing wrong but problem is not there

Comment: Please use the query builder and not this Active Record Antipattern.

Comment: @odan hi, odan, you mean the each() function given below?

Comment: @bgul Yes, in this context, updating multiple records in a loop is a real antipattern.

Comment: Thanks for the information odan :) I changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$img` seems to be a query builder object.

If you do `$img = Images::where('project_id', '=', $project->id)->get();` you will get everything that needs updading example:

```
 $index = 1;
 Images::where('project_id', '=', $project->id)->get()
        ->each(function ($img) use (&$index) {
              $img->order_num = $index++;
              $img->save();
         });
```

This will update all image indices for a single project id. If you want to do all of them then you can do:

```
 $index = 0;
 $lastProjectId = null;
 Images::orderBy('project_id')->get()
        ->each(function ($img) use (&$index, $lastProjectId) {
              if ($lastProjectId == null) {
                 $lastProjectId = $img->project_id; 
              }   
              if ($img->project_id != $lastProjectId) {
                 $index = 1;
                 $lastProjectId = $img->project_id;
              }
              $img->order_num = $index++;
              $img->save();
         });
```

Comment: Thanks for your helps @apokryfos. I haven't heard the each() method(I have to do some research about this).  Thanks for your additional code for upgrade all values

Answer (score 2):

try simply this

```
$imgs = Images::where('project_id', '=', $project->id)->get();
foreach($imgs as $i => $img) {
    $img->order_id = $i + 1;
    $img->save();
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer.  I think the problem is caused by for loop... But this one works perfectly. Thanks again.

Comment: you may need to do `$img = Images::where('project_id', '=', $project->id)->get()->values()` . There's a chance the collection result is keyed by the id.

Comment: It works well without values(). But i'll keep that in mind thanks for your sharing knowledge. :)