# Eloquent each() method returns zero value

Tags: laravel, eloquent, slim-3

This question is related to [Eloquent save() method not working inside for loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53470245/eloquent-save-method-not-working-inside-for-loop).

**PROCESS MAP: UPLOAD FILES > CREATE TABLE ROWS WITH DEFAULT VALUE 0 > CONTINUE TO ITERATE OVER 0 PARTS(Eg If last one 3-> 4,5,6 )**

I want to continue add images to the specific project after first image upload process.

**$input['id']: holding project id value.**

I do apply each() method like this:

```
*** code part executed after multiple file upload ***

TABLE STATUS AT FIRST STAGE :
+---------+-------------+-----------+
| id      | project_id  | order_id  |  
+---------+-------------+-----------+
| 1       | 15          | 1         |
+---------+-------------+-----------+
| 2       | 15          | 2         |
+---------+-------------+-----------+
| 3       | 16          | 1         |  --> Added in the past
+---------+-------------+-----------+
| 4       | 16          | 0         |  --> Created on first stage** : default 0.
+---------+-------------+-----------+ 
| 5       | 16          | 0         |  --> Created on first stage** : default 0.
+---------+-------------+-----------+


*** code continues ***

$start = Images::select('order_id')->where('project_id', '=', $input['id'])
->orderBy('order_id', 'DESC')->first();  

Images::where('project_id', '=', $input['id'])->where('order_id', '=', 0)->get()
       ->each(function($ord) use (&$start) {
              $ord->order_id = $start++;
              $ord->save();
});
```

Table results after the code given above executed (still in process)

```
+---------+-------------+-----------+
| id      | project_id  | order_id  |  
+---------+-------------+-----------+
| 1       | 15          | 1         |
+---------+-------------+-----------+
| 2       | 15          | 2         |
+---------+-------------+-----------+
| 3       | 16          | 1         |  --> Added in the past
+---------+-------------+-----------+
| 4       | 16          | 0         |  --> New / Present Action : 1st file 
+---------+-------------+-----------+ 
| 5       | 16          | 0         |  --> New / Present Action : 2nd one
+---------+-------------+-----------+
```

**Expectation:**

```
+---------+-------------+-----------+
| id      | project_id  | order_id  |  
+---------+-------------+-----------+
| 1       | 15          | 1         |
+---------+-------------+-----------+
| 2       | 15          | 2         |
+---------+-------------+-----------+
| 3       | 16          | 1         |  --> Added in the past
+---------+-------------+-----------+
| 4       | 16          | 2         |  --> New / Present Action : 1st file 
+---------+-------------+-----------+ 
| 5       | 16          | 3         |  --> New / Present Action : 2nd one
+---------+-------------+-----------+
```

What's the problem? Wrong logic or each() ? i don't know but i tried with foreach and i got same wrong results. Any help would be very appreciated. Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try accessing the id property when incrementing.

```
Images::where('project_id', '=', $input['id'])->where('order_id', '=', 0)->get()
       ->each(function($ord) use (&$start) {
              $ord->order_id = $start->id++;
              $ord->save();
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer @adis. My stupid fault :D

Comment: No problem. Goodluck :)

Answer (score 1):

```
$start = Images::select('order_id')->where('project_id', '=', $input['id'])
->orderBy('order_id', 'DESC')->first();
```

Returns an object of `Images`

$start->order_id should contain your id-number

Comment: Hi @Artur Smolen, thanks for the important point. Now it works :D. My fault :/ :D